# Construct a callable argument in embedded Python with Python C API

Tags: python, function-pointers, python-c-api

I am writing code that starts in Python, then goes to C via `ctypes` and inside C it uses Python embedding to invoke a Python function, that is, the flow looks like this:

```
Python user code passes function name -> C mediator library -> Python "backend code"
```

1. Python user code loads C mediator library and passes to it a function name `funcname` and its arguments (types and values) via `ctypes`.
2. C mediator library embeds Python, loads required module and call
   the function with `funcname` and passed arguments.
3. Embedded Python execute the function and returns result.

The Python function accepts different parameters and one of them
is a callback function. When I am at the C mediator library, I have a `void` pointer to this callback. *Question*: How to convert it to a Python `callable`?

Thank you!

Minimal (not-)working example consists of files `run.py` (user code), `callstuff.c` (C mediator library), `dostuff.py` (Python "backend" code) and `CMakeLists.txt` to compile the C mediator library.

```py
# File run.py
import ctypes
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if sys.platform == "darwin":
        ext = "dylib"
    elif sys.platform == "linux":
        ext = "so"
    else:
        raise ValueError("Handle me somehow")

    lib = ctypes.PyDLL(f"build/libcallstuff.{ext}")
    initialize = lib.__getattr__("initialize")
    initialize()
    call = lib.__getattr__("call")
    # signature: int call(char *funcname, void * fn_p, int x)
    call.restype = ctypes.c_int
    call.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_int]

    def myfn(x):
        return 2 * x

    # Prepare all arguments to call func
    # fn_p signature is int f(int x)
    fn_t = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, *[ctypes.c_int])
    fn_p = ctypes.cast(ctypes.pointer(fn_t(myfn)), ctypes.c_void_p)
    a = ctypes.c_int(21)

    result = call("apply".encode(), fn_p, a)
    print("Result is", result)
    finalize = lib.__getattr__("finalize")
    finalize()
```

```c
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


/**
 * This function invokes function `func` from the Python module `dostuff.py`
 * via Python embedding.
 * Here, the function is constrained, as the other arguments are passed
 * explicitly because there is only one value of `func` for this example.
 * In general case, it will be a list that carries types information as ints
 * and void pointers to values.
 * All memory release and error checks are omitted.
 */
int call(const char *fn_name, void *fn_p, int x) {
    printf("I am here\n");
    PyObject *pFileName = PyUnicode_FromString("dostuff");
    printf("I am here 2\n");
    PyObject *pModule = PyImport_Import(pFileName);
    printf("I am here 3\n");

    PyObject *pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, fn_name);
    PyObject *pArgs = PyTuple_New(2); // We have args: f, a, b

    PyObject *pValue;
    pValue = (PyObject *) fn_p; // ??????? How to convert void *fn_p?
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);

    pValue = PyLong_FromLong(x);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pValue);

    PyObject *pResult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);

    if (pResult != NULL) {
        return PyLong_AsLong(pResult);
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

int initialize() {
    Py_Initialize();
    return 0;
}

int finalize() {
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

```py
# file dostuff.py
from typing import Callable


def apply(f: Callable, x):
    return f(x)
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(PyCInterop LANGUAGES C)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

find_package(Python REQUIRED Interpreter Development)

add_library(callstuff SHARED callstuff.c)
target_link_libraries(callstuff PRIVATE Python::Python)
```

To compile:

```bash
$ cmake -S. -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug && cmake --build build
```

To run:

```bash
$ python run.py
```

Comment: I think you'd just need a `PyObject *`, which is how that function should be defined in the first place. Maybe the question is how it got to be a `void *`?

Comment: Write a [mcve] to give us context.

Comment: A callable is anything that implements the tp_call or vectorcall protocols (see [Call protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/call.html#call-protocol)). You pass any generic object and it is checked dynamically for whether it is callable.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I have added an example. Thank you

Comment: @tdelaney It is `void *` as the function pointer could be from Python, C, or other languages. All arguments are passed between different languages as void pointers along with type identifiers and then converted to corresponding types on the receiving side (for example, C `double` is converted to Python `float`).

Comment: You want to callback Python function from C that takes a callback, correct?  You don't need Python embedding for that.  See the [`Callback functions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions) section in the `ctypes` module documentation.  It shows how to call C `qsort()` with a Python callback.

Comment: Another option is to use `ctypes.py_object` instead of `ctypes.c_void_p` as the argument type in the top-level Python.  C can receive it as a `PyObject*` (or a `void*`, but then it must be cast) and then pass that to another Python function that is executed via Python embedding if you really need that.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion of `ctypes.py_object`. I have managed to get some success by casting python callable to pointer via `py_fn_p = id(fn)` and then casting to `void` pointer via `ctypes`. Then I could recast the void pointer in C to `PyObject *` and it is Python callable that can be passed as an argument to a function in embedded python.

Comment: I have to use embedded Python, because C level represents some mediator library that passes function invokation from one language to another. (it does not have to be Python -> C -> Python, it is just the path that I am doing right now). However, the way I solved it now works only because I actually pass Python callable, if it is a function pointer in, say, C, my above-comment solution will not work.